# void is an invalid type for the variable paint

Tags: java, applet

void is an invalid type for the variable paint is the error i am getting by the way my program is when you click the checkbox the textfield shows the checkbox name in textfield thank you!
Using if statement*..........

```
package irt;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class chkBx extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
    TextField t1;
    Checkbox c1,c2,c3;
    Label l1;
    public void init()
    {
        l1=new Label("data");
        add(l1);
        t1=new TextField(15);
        add(t1);
        c1=new Checkbox("nashik");
        add(c1);
        c2=new Checkbox("pune");
        add(c2);
        c3=new Checkbox("mumbai");
        add(c3);
        c1.addItemListener(this);
        c2.addItemListener(this);
        c3.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
        String msg="state";

                    public void paint(Graphics g)

                        {

                            t1.setText(msg);    
                            g.drawString(msg,50,100);
                            msg="city"+c1.getState();
                        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Just move one of the last `}` after `msg = "state";` but before `public void paint(...`. You messed up the bracing there. BTW: There is no such thing as an 'if-loop'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `public void paint(Graphics g)` con not be a part of the method `itemStateChanged`.

You have to change your code:

```
public class chkBx extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
  String msg = new String();

  TextField t1;
  Checkbox c1, c2, c3;
  Label l1;

  public void init() {
    l1 = new Label("data");
    add(l1);
    t1 = new TextField(15);
    add(t1);
    c1 = new Checkbox("nashik");
    add(c1);
    c2 = new Checkbox("pune");
    add(c2);
    c3 = new Checkbox("mumbai");
    add(c3);
    c1.addItemListener(this);
    c2.addItemListener(this);
    c3.addItemListener(this);
  }

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    String msg = "state";
    this.repaint();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)

  {

    t1.setText(msg);
    g.drawString(msg, 50, 100);
    msg = "city" + c1.getState();
  }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if i understand you right. But you can add the ItemListener only to the first checkbox.

Comment: I mean if the first checkbox is checked then execute this....if 2nd checkbox is checked then execute this ...like that i mean Is it possible in Java?

Comment: @theUndisputedHacker Yes  `if (e.getSource().equals(c1)&& c1.getState()== true)` e.getSource() gives you the element which is clicked and getState() gives you the information if it is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you cannot define a method inside a method.

You need to define the method `paint` outside of the method `itemStateChanged`:

```
public void paint(Graphics g, String msg) {
    t1.setText(msg);    
    g.drawString(msg, 50, 100);
}
```